# Telethon. How send Album with button?

Tags: button, bots, telethon

Telethon
I need to forward an album to a channel with a button without using forward. When I do `send_message` or `send_file`, the message comes without the button.
How to send Album with button.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import events, Button


@bot.on(events.NewMessage(chats=gasket_group))
async def handler(event):
    message = event.message
    file = message.media
    if message.grouped_id:
        return
    button = Button.inline("Send")
    await bot.send_message(admin_target_group_id, message.message, file=message.media, buttons=button)


@bot.on(events.Album(chats=gasket_group))
async def album_resend_handler(event):
    print('messages from album_resend_handler:', event.messages)
    button = Button.inline("Send")
    files = event.messages
    text_message = event.messages[0].message
    await bot.send_file(admin_target_group_id, file=files, caption=text_message,allow_cache=True, buttons=button)
    # await bot.send_message(admin_target_group_id, event.messages[0].message, file=files, buttons=button)
```

I need to forward a message by adding a button to it from a group. Texting and sending a single file works correctly, but when forwarding an album, the message arrives without a button.

Answer (score 0):

[SendMultiMedia](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/send_multi_media.html) request, used when you pass list of files, doesn't take reply_makrup/buttons.

Telegram API doesn't allow buttons to be attached to albums/grouped media for internal reasons

Comment: How can I do this any way?